# Windows 7 touch screen PC - disable pinch to zoom in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, zooming, pinchzoom

I have a kiosk computer with a touch screen and Windows Embedded POSready 7.

I then have a WPF application with only a WebBrowser inside, that launch a website. (The WebBrowser uses Internet Explorer engine)

In this website, I would like to prevent zooming on the page with a pinch to zoom.

I tried things like :

```
html {
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

But it doesn't works.

What is the page event for a "pinch" ? Maybe I can replace this behavior...

Is there a way to do it ? Even if it's a workaround method... I absolutely need to prevent zooming on the page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have observed is that the pinch gesture is tied to the browser Zoom level. So I don't know if this can be controlled from within an HTML document. You can change this behavior in the registry though, and this might be a solution for you, since you are operating a kiosk:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/86756-internet-explorer-zoom-enable-disable.html

Another solution could be to disable the pinch-zoom behavior in your OS. In other words, disable Control Panel - Mouse- Device Settings - Settings - PINCH ZOOM.

Answer (score 1):

You were right with your code :

```
html {
  -ms-content-zooming: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

the problem is that these properties are only implemented in the Windows 8 version (or later) of IE. (see requirements here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771891(v=vs.85).aspx)

For Win7 IE10+ you'll have to change the browser or OS settings as Jean-François Beauchamp said above.

For Win8+ IE10+, Microsoft has a listing of all events and CSS properties to manage the zoom or other functions. See it here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772726(v=vs.85).aspx